# How to make a graph of bank account data in excel with a table of balance changes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, accounting

I have an excel table with dates and according bank account balances. Now I add a graph and get the following:

[image]

The graph should have a timeline on the x-axis - that works. But I want the data to be shown as follows:

[image]

So that I can see account balance mapped to time. Unfortunately Excel connects the dots with a line - I don't want that. How can I achieve the second graph?

Thanks!

Comment: use a bar chart instead of line chart.

Answer (score 3):

To get the effect you want you will need to use a normal bar graph and change some of the options. Here is a tutorial you can follow. I've edited to make it easier to understand for less skilled excel users. Here is the final result after following the tutorial.

[image]

---

**Chart**

1. Select both data without the headers
2. Go to the tab "Insert"
3. Click on the dropdown list "Insert collumn or bar chart"
4. Click on "Clustered Collumn"

[image: Clustered Collumn]

5. Then click on a bar and make sure its selected (it will have blue
   dots on the edges.
6. Click on the "Plus sign" hover over axes click on the arrow and then
   more options.

[image]

7. Now select the bars again and an option menu should appear on the
   right
8. Make the "Gap Width" 0%

[image]

---

**Data points format**

To make the dates align.

1. Click on one of the dates in the graph to select them
2. Open the menu. See step 5 - 6 from Chart.
3. Click on one of the dates to select them again.
4. Now in the option menu select the option "On Tick marks"
5. At the dropdown "Tick Marks" change the Major type to "Inside"

[image]

Comment: With this type of graph, the x-axis is not a timeline anymore but simly the data points in the table. What I want is to have a timeline on the x-axis to really see balance change over time

Comment: @MathiasBader How do you mean? When I change my data to match your it looks 100% exactly like how you want it. here take a look http://imgur.com/a/59j6p

Comment: I either get a chart where each data point has equal width (which I don't want), or I get a chart where the datapoints correspond to the dates, but then there will be a lot of empty space between the bars

Comment: Look at the chart in my question: The entries in the table for dates are not the same as the text on the x-axis

Comment: @MathiasBader I get what you mean. That is also an option. I'll add it to my answer. I'll try to find the english version aswell.

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't seem to work for me. Made an example to show what I get if I follow your hints: http://imgur.com/a/DCD2Z A lot of empty space :-(.

Comment: @MathiasBader It does work but the data for the date 01.02.2016 is 0 so it creates a bar that is 0. Could you give me the download link for the file? if you want something like per day/month you would need to change the interval.

Comment: @MathiasBader I found out that for a timeline on the X-axis like you have can only be done with linecharts since they predict the growth for each day that has 0 inbetween. You could however upload the excel file that has some problems and I'll ee what I can do.