# Excel graph of 2500 date-based data rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I've an excel spreadsheet with 2800+ rows of data in the form: date, $amount. The rows are from dates 1/1/2004 through 2/26/2017. Not every date is listed, but most are.

I'd like to produce a graph that shows the values at month intervals. Sure I could manipulate the data set to do that, but I know there's and easier way to get this displayed on a simple Line Chart.

Comment: Are the dates already in a certain order like per day, week or month?

Comment: I think a normal line chart would be best for you. The changes for the difference between days in a months will be so little that you probably won't see them in the chart.

Comment: You likely don['t want a line chart.  Line charts automatically treat the horizontal axis as categorical values.  You should (almost always) use an XY(Scatter) chart so your horizontal values are properly scaled.

Answer (score 0):

From my answer here you can see how to get the Axis Option menu.
[How to make a graph of bank account data in excel with a table of balance changes?](https://superuser.com/questions/1182348/how-to-make-a-graph-of-bank-account-data-in-excel-with-a-table-of-balance-change/1182352#1182352)

By displaying the data chart per month you would need to select the Months units under the Axis Option. For a data with 2800+ rows it will going to look like this:

[image]